# How to tell ANTLR not to consume token

Tags: antlr

How can i tell Antlr not to consume a token, rather just skip it and then come back to it latter?
I am trying to evaluate Haskell-like list building and print the newly formed list 
ex: [2x+3| x<-list1]. so what i need is to first read list1, then come back and evaluate the expression 2x+3.

Any suggestions of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ANTLR in a few years, but from what I remember ANTLR actions let you store intermediate results in variables, and reference them later. In that case, you can store `2x+3` in some intermediate variable, then once you've read `list1` you can go back and evaluate the intermediate value you stored since you now have the necessary context.